# Como formatar um array php

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Estou fazendo uma consulta SQL no meu *model* e no *controller*, estou imprimindo os valores do *array*.

A exibição esta assim:

```
Array ( [campo1] => 98 [campo2] => SOLO [soma] => 1 ) Array ( [campo1] => 92 [campo2] => DARTH [soma] => 11 ).
```

Mas gostaria de formatar assim:

```
[campo1] => 98 =>[campo2] => 
            SOLO [soma] => 1
[campo2] => 92 =>[campo2] => 
            DARTH [soma] => 11
```

Como fazer?

Esse é o meu *foreach*:

```
foreach ($variavel1 as $key) {
   print_r($key);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, posta o método em questão todo do seu controller pra melhor análise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vejamos você está imprimindo  uma subarray que é encontrada pelo for each  se  você quiser imprimila desta forma você estará deixando de ter uma array  e  passarar a ter um  string 
pode fazer isso pela função implode

```
foreach ($variavel1 as $key) {
    $output = implode(', ', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) { return sprintf("[%s]=>'%s'", $k, $v); },
        $key,
        array_keys($key)
    ));
    echo $output."\n";
}
```

isso imprimirá algo como

```
[campo1]=>'98', [campo2]=>'SOLO', [soma]=>'1' 
[campo1]=>'92', [campo2]=>'DARTH', [soma]=>'11'
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja ver o conteúdo do array não é necessário executar um `foreach`, basta utilizar a tag `pre` do HTML em conjunto com a função `print_r` do PHP desta forma:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [campo1] => 98
        [campo2] => SOLO
        [soma] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [campo1] => 92
        [campo2] => DARTH
        [soma] => 11
    )

)
```

A tag `pre` tem o objetivo de facilitar a leitura dos dados, preservando os espaços e quebras de linha retornados pelo `print_r`.

E a função `print_r` quando tem o segundo parâmetro informado como `true` ao invés de imprimir, retorna a informação para podermos utilizar como desejarmos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente user o VarDumper do próprio Yii2

```
\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($array, 10, true);
```

É um pouco diferente do jeito que ilustrou, mas dessa forma fica bem claro